# Getting all populated places per state when number of places over 6000

Tags: geonames

I am able to query for the number of places.  The problem becomes when there are over 6000 places, the system gives me an error message that the requested start row is too big.

Here is an example of a request which would generate that:

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PPL&username=genadinik&country=US&style=full&adminCode1=VA&maxRows=1000&startRow=6000

How do people usually get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the data dump and put it into PostGIS. See http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/geonames/index.html for more details.

Comment: Yeah, but then how do I query the data dump if it is downloaded?  Will I be able to put it into some sort of MySQL structure?  Is that straight forward?

Comment: Yes, PostGIS is a database like MySQL. Just better ;)

Comment: @Genadinik: Yes, querying a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database is as straight forward as your URL: SELECT * FROM geoname WHERE fcode='PPL' AND country='US' AND admincode1='VA';